# How can I recreate Snapchat's built-in filter effects?

Tags: photoshop, plugin, software-filters

I found some plugins for Photoshop that got all the Instagram filters and similar features, but nowhere can I find an action file or a plugin for Photoshop that can recreate Snapchat's built-in filters for pictures. I am NOT talking about anything related to the Geofilters, which is apparently the only thing that can be found online regarding Snapchat...

After taking a picture and swiping right in Snapchat you can get a filter that makes the picture lighter, then more subtle and darker, followed by a more vivid colorful filter, and at last a simple B&W filter.

Does anyone know of a plugin for that? Or an actionfile (`.atn` file)? Or can someone explain how to at least get the vivid colourful effect which happens in the 3rd filter? That would be much appreciated!

Looking forward to some ideas :)

Below is a example image of the 3rd filter which I took:

[image: Example Picture]

Comment: Please also include the original file. Makes the whole process of determining how x became y just a tad easier.

Comment: there is unfortunately no original :/ it's just the pink"ish" filter over the whole picture and some more colour enhancements but that's all I can tell you. @Hueco

Comment: This is too broad — can you break it down to the specific "filter" you want to analyze?

Comment: Yes, the 3rd filter when swiping to the right after taking a picture inside Snapchat. @mattdm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just a warming filter it seems, I know you want the "official snapchat filter" in your photoshop presets, but unfortunately you're not going to find that intellectual property. I would suggest looking through other presets such as some instagram presets to find one that warms the photo and adjusts the saturation and brightness close to the filter in snapchat you like. from the research I've done snapchat filters are constantly changing, and you cannot find names for any of the filters to even have a starting point of what to look for. even if you did you would never truly find the exact filter.

I suggest taking a photo with your cellphone, and sending it to your computer to try out filters on, while also having it loaded into snapchat, with the filter you like placed on the original photo, that way you have something to reference to the presets you're trying out to find the closest option.

just remember you will be searching for presets, and a lot are paid, but you can still find quite a few free ones.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look this up! Yeah I kind of thought so too, I'll just go with an trial and error approach like you suggested.